# How to refresh RecyclerView of hidden fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have two `Fragments` A and B with `RecyclerView` list.
When fragment A is active I call:

```
 fragmentTransaction.hide(Frag_A);
```

and I add **fragment B** with command:

```
 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, Frag_B);
```

When **fragment B** is active and I do some changes I need to silently call:

```
 mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

on **Fragment A**.
So it is possible to call this, when fragment is hidden?
Now I am using

```
@Override
 public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
      super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
    }
```

But this method is triggered when I am going back from fragment B to A.
I want to refresh **fragment A** when **fragment B** is active. (User see fragment B list).
How to do that?

Comment: Have you considered to use `replace` instead `add` ?

Comment: Yes, but **Fragment A** has full list, when user doesn't make any changes I don't want to refresh whole list, after back from Fragment B to A in every time. I want to refresh this list only when user change some data in  **Fragment B** and back to  **Fragment A**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to refresh data in FragmentA while FragmentB is active.

First, you have create an Interface

```
interface FragmentCallback {
   fun onResumeFragment()
}
```

Next, before you want to go to `FragmentA`, you are using `add` method. So, you have to add a `tag`for `FragmentA`.

```
private fun loadFragmentA(someId: Int) {
    val bun = Bundle()
    bun.apply {
        putInt(Constant.SOME_ID, someId)
    }
    val fragmentA = FragmentA()
    fragmentA.arguments = bun
    val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction =
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.add(
        R.id.fragment_container,
        fragmentA,
        "TagFragmentA"
    )
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

At the `MainActivity`, you need to implement the interface that we created. inside the `onResumeFragment` method, we have to find that `FragmentA` by using `tag`. So, we can use the method inside that `fragment`.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FragmentCallback {

    override fun onResumeFragment() {
        val fragmentA =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("TagFragmentA") as FragmentA
        fragmentA.refreshData()
    }
}
```

Inside `FragmentA`, create `refreshData` method and make it public. So inside this method, you can notify the data changed.

```
fun refreshData(){
    viewModel.getListSomething()
}
```

Inside `FragmentB`, you need to override the `onAttach` method to make the object for `FragmentCallback`.

```
private var fragmentCallback: FragmentCallback? = null
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is FragmentCallback) {
        fragmentCallback = context
    } else {
        throw RuntimeException(
            context.javaClass.simpleName
                .toString() + " must implement FragmentCallback"
        )
    }
}
```

Finally create a method to trigger when there is data changes.

```
private fun timeToUpdateDataAtFragmentA(){
    fragmentCallback?.onResumeFragment()
}
```

When you from `FragmentB`, back press to `FragmentA`, the data will update at the `FragmentA`.

Comment: Yes. It is working thanks. I already have an interface. But I had some errors.. never mind... I have two questions.       
If I write  "fragmentCallback = context" in onViewCreated I get an error but if I did it in  onAttach method problem disappears like you present to me. Why is this happening? We always should pass context to interface in onAttach? why not in onViewCreated or on Create?

Comment: Second: You write viewModel.getListSomething(); My LiveData works ok, I only needed refresh the RecyclerView so I used mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanges(). It is ok? Or I should download the list again  using viemodel and then refresh Adapter with new data from VieModel or can I only refresh alone recyclerView, like I did it?

Comment: @L23ko 1. `onViewCreated` , there is no `context` provided compared to `onAttach`. The `context` will pass through `onAttach`. So it is useable once the Fragment attached. 2. I think you have to try it by yourself. So you will know which one is the best for your requirements.